# How to set up "mixed" boundary conditions for NDSolve for PDE?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

I have the following PDE that I am able to solve using `DirichletCondition` with `NDSolve` as the following:

```
uu = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[U[x, y], {x, y}] == 10*Sin[8*x*(y - 1)], 
    DirichletCondition[U[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
   U, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}];
Plot3D[Evaluate[uu[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {-.5, .5}}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]]
```

This works for me and it matches my numerical solution from MATLAB. However, I was trying to solve a similar PDE with different BCs. A Dirichlet BC on y with interval {-1,1} and a periodic BC on x with interval {0,2*pi}. I have a numerical solution in MATLAB that I would like to reproduce with Mathematica. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: **I have a numerical solution in MATLAB that I would like to reproduce with Mathematica. Is this possible?** could you show that Matlab code?

Comment: What means "Dirichlet BC on y with interval {-1,1} "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand the boundary conditions try

```
    reg = Rectangle[ {0, -1}, {2 Pi, 1}  ];
V = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[v[x, y], {x, y}] == 10*Sin[8*x*(y - 1)], 
   DirichletCondition[v[x, y] == 0, y == 1 || y == -1],
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[x, y], x == 2 Pi && -1 < y < 1, 
    TranslationTransform[{-2 Pi, 0}]],
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[x, y], x == 0 && -1 < y < 1, 
    TranslationTransform[{ 2 Pi, 0}]]}, v, Element[{x, y}, reg ], 
  Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
    "MeshOptions" -> {"MeshElementType" -> "TriangleElement", 
        "MaxCellMeasure" -> 2 Pi/1000 }}]
Plot3D[V[x, y], Element[{x, y}, reg], PlotRange -> All, 
 MeshFunctions -> (#3 &)]
```

[image]

In this example Mathematica v12.2 only handles `PeriodicBoundaryConditions` correctly if we use `"MeshElementType" -> "TriangleElement"`